# Mobile Wallet location based notification mechanism

Tags: push-notification, geofencing, google-pay, location-based, apple-wallet

I am very new to mobile wallet and I have received the requirements that:

- our customer will publish a loyalty membership pass that users can install in their mobile wallet (Google pay, Apple wallet).
- When users with mobile wallet enter our customer's property, they will receive a notification on what they should do next.

Based on what I investigated in the document of Google pay and Apple Wallet, they support location based notification, but I am not quite understand the detail.

I have some questions here:

1. How will the location data be handled? Does mobile wallet send location data every xx min interval and some servers out there will check and push notification based on what we setup via the loyalty pass?
2. Can we customize these notification for every customer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Based on what I investigated in the document of Google pay and Apple Wallet, they support location based notification

Note that according to [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/pass-verticals/use-cases?authuser=0&vertical=loyalty#geofenced-notifications):

> **Important**: Geofenced notifications are temporarily unavailable for a majority of users while we make platform improvements. We'll completely update this feature in an upcoming release.

---

> 1. How will the location data be handled? Does mobile wallet send location data every xx min interval and some servers out there will check and push notification based on what we setup via the loyalty pass?

I don't know how this actually works. Any answer I try to provide will be pure speculation. The technical implementation could also be different between Google and Apple.

---

> 2. Can we customize these notification for every customer?

For Google at least, the notification cannot be customized.